# value of a $\frac{ p_t(z)}{z^m}$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology

Fundamental Theorem of Algebra by using Algebraic topology

In [wikipidea](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Algebra) it is written that

> let $p(z)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ ;

> $p(z)=z^m +a_1z^{m-1} +\cdots+ a_m$

> Define a homotopy: $p_t(z)=tp(z) + (1-t)z^m$
> then
> $$\frac{ p_t(z)}{z^m} =1  + t \left(\frac{a_1}{z} +\cdots+\frac{a_m}{z}\right)$$

**My doubt** :Im not getting why $\frac{p_t(z)}{z^m} =1  + t (\frac{a_1}{z} +\cdots+\frac{a_m}{z})\text{?}$

**My thinking** :

\begin{align}
& \frac{ p_t(z)}{z^m} =\frac{tp(z)}{z^m}  + \frac{(1-t)z^m}{z^m} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{tp(z)}{z^m}+(1-t)\neq1  + t \left(\frac{a_1}{z} +\cdots+\frac{a_m}{z}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Your link is not to Wikipedia, but rather to Proof Wiki. I don't think that is affiliated with Wikipedia or the Wikimedia Foundation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought  that it was wikipidea because both  starts with a **Wiki** word

Comment: By that theory, Wikileaks would be affiliated with Wikipedia, which would be scandalous. But "wiki" is a common noun, meaning a publicly editable web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_t(z) = tp(z) + (1-t)z^m = z^m + t(p(z) - z^m)$ so $$\frac{p_t(z)}{z^m} = 1 + t(\frac{p(z)}{z^m} - 1) = 1 + t(1 + \frac{a_1}{z} + \frac{a_2}{z^2} + \cdots + \frac{a_m}{z^{m-1}} - 1) = \\ 1+t(\frac{a_1}{z} + \frac{a_2}{z^2} + \cdots + \frac{a_m}{z^{m-1}})$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
& \xcancel{\frac{ p_t(z)}{z^m} =1  + t \left(\frac{a_1}{z} +\cdots+\frac{a_m}{z}\right)} \\[10pt]
& \frac{p_t(z)}{z^m} = 1  + t \left(\frac{a_1}{z} +\cdots+\frac{a_m}{z^m} \right) \\[8pt]
& \frac{p_t(z)}{z^m} = \frac{tp(z) + (1-t)z^m}{z^m} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{tz^m + t\big(a_1z^{m-1} +\cdots+ a_m\big) + (1-t)z^m}{z^m} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{z^m + t\big(a_1z^{m-1} + \cdots + a_m\big)}{z^m}
\end{align}
$$